# PHP MYSQL QUERY VALIDATION

Tags: php, validation

whats wrong with my program here? I can't seem to work the "word not found" ? :/

```
echo "<form action='#' method='post'>";
echo "Search word here: <input type='text' name='search'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='searchword' value='Search'>";
echo "</form>";
if(isset($_POST['searchword'])){
    $word = $_POST['search'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM positivethesaurus where word like '%$word%'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    echo $row['word']."<br>";
    }
    if($row = mysql_fetch_array(!$result)){
        echo "word not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: FYI, you also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: Practice makes perfect ;)

Comment: @F4r-20 haha true and i got the answer now my mistake was i placed the exclamation mark on my $result when it should be on '!$row' so thanks :D

Comment: Do not mix presentation with business logic. See this: http://blog.iandavis.com/2008/12/09/what-are-the-benefits-of-mvc

Answer (score 3):

I think you are assigning the value to `$word` with wrong fieldname

```
$word = $_POST['search'];
```

It should be

```
$word = $_POST['searchword'];
```

I am just guessing because you are checking if it is set with this field name.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: the searchword name is my submit name

Answer (score 1):

your posting value is wrong. Change to,

```
$word = $_POST['searchword'];
```

from,

```
$word = $_POST['search'];
```

Comment: its still not working here's the error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\EIMS\searchbypositive.php on line 25

Comment: @troubledone This error occurs only if your query returns false. Check your query whether it returns any result.

Comment: got it :)! i should be placing my exclamation mark or null on the $row from that to this !$row :D

Answer (score 0):

word is maybe a reserved term, try this

```
"SELECT * FROM positivethesaurus where `word` like '%$word%'"
```

Comment: Nice idea, but `word` isn't a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)